# Compiling error using Vue loader and AWS Amplify

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

When running vue-cli-service build I get this error. I don't know what's is missing.

> NODE_ENV=development vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./models in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/detailpage/ranking/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
```

It should be caused by this:

```
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { Rankings } from './models';
```

Models contains typescripts files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved replacing `./` with `@`

```
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { Rankings } from '@/models';
```